# Test-Framework for private constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

For my JUnit-tests I'm using frameworks like Hamcrest and Mockito but none of them give me Matchers or something like this to test private constructors.

I know there a ways to test this like descriped here:

- http://wiki.ivonet.nl/display/JAVA/JUnit+test+private+constructors
- [How to test a private constructor in Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077842/how-to-test-a-private-constructor-in-java-application)
- [How to add test coverage to a private constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520216/how-to-add-test-coverage-to-a-private-constructor)

But I have more then one class with private constructors, so I don't want to duplicate code.
Before I write my own testtools I wanna ask if there is any framework which can test my private constructors and test the class has no other constructor etc.

[UPDATE]

- Found http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/org/jvnet/hudson/test/JenkinsMatchers.html but its not jenkins tasks to provide testtools.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect by testing the private constructor? E.g. you're trying to test a singleton you should have a method returning the instance. So you could test the constructor implicit.

Comment: Increase my code coverage and taking care about that there will never be a constructor. There is no Constructor need because all methods are static.

Comment: If it's never constructed, why test it??

Comment: As I said for my test coverage and i want that there'll be no constructor ever.For Example i can ensure if one of my team members do some code there, they'll never add constructors.

Comment: @kdoteu - if you have only static utility methods, your unit tests should test just them! There is nothing what you really could test on a private constructor. You may write a test that (mis)uses some reflection magick to test if all constructors are private, but this gains you next to nothing.

Comment: @kdoteu In case it is just for increasing the test coverage you should recap the reply in the post you just linked about the test coverage of a private constructor. In my view it is not worth to test to pimp the stats.

Comment: @mbeat I agree the fact it's stupid to this only to increase the coverage. But I want to ensure nobody will add some constructors to a class with only static methods. Therefore i need a test for this.

Comment: @GyroGearless i know the way to test private constructors. But i want to test this in more then one class. And as I wrote at the beginning before I write sth. on my own I want to ask if there is already sth done.

Comment: @kdoteu You could make the class abstract so it cannot be instantiated. Also, what would happens if somebody would actually add a constructor and instantiates the class?

Comment: @Bart but so nobody can extends this class and this should be possible.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts, but I dont want to discuss if I should Test or not. I only wanted to know if there is any framework who is doing alle the stuff for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you could either exclude the method (more coverage) or making it accessible for tests (Not good idea)