# Is it possible to call constructor on existing instance?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, unsafe

It is known that using `sun.misc.Unsafe#allocateInstance` one can create an object without calling any class constructors.

Is it possible to do the opposite: given an existing instance, invoke a constructor on it?

---

**Clarification**: this is not the question about something I'd do in production code. I'm curious about JVM internals and crazy things that can still be done. Answers specific to some JVM version are welcome.

Comment: If you're asking about JVM internals, you're not asking about Java as a language.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm asking if there is a way to do what I'm asking about, by whatever means necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JVMS §2.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9) forbids invocation of constructor on already initialized objects:

> Instance initialization methods may be invoked only within the Java
>   Virtual Machine by the invokespecial instruction, and
>   they may be invoked only on uninitialized class instances.

However, it is still **technically possible** to invoke constructor on initialized object with **JNI**. [CallVoidMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#calltypemethod-routines-calltypemethoda-routines-calltypemethodv-routines) function does not make difference between `<init>` and ordinary Java methods. Moreover, JNI specification hints that `CallVoidMethod` *may* be used to call a constructor, though it does not say whether an instance has to be initialized or not:

> When these functions are **used to call** private methods and **constructors**, the method ID must be derived from the real class of obj, not from one of its superclasses.

I've verified that the following code works both in JDK 8 and JDK 9. JNI allows you to do unsafe things, but you **should not rely** on this in production applications.

**ConstructorInvoker.java**

```
public class ConstructorInvoker {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("constructorInvoker");
    }

    public static native void invoke(Object instance);
}
```

**constructorInvoker.c**

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_ConstructorInvoker_invoke(JNIEnv* env, jclass self, jobject instance) {
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, instance);
    jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "()V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, instance, constructor);
}
```

**TestObject.java**

```
public class TestObject {
    int x;

    public TestObject() {
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
        x++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestObject obj = new TestObject();
        System.out.println("x = " + obj.x);  // x = 1

        ConstructorInvoker.invoke(obj);
        System.out.println("x = " + obj.x);  // x = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the really interesting question… what will happen if `TestObject` has a nontrivial `finalize()` method?

Comment: @Holger Excellent question! By default, HotSpot JVM registers finalizers at the end of `Object.<init>`. That is, `finalize()` can be called twice for the same object. With `-XX:-RegisterFinalizersAtInit` flag finalizers are registered right after the object allocations, so `finalize()` will be called just once.

Comment: Oh. It’s interesting that there is an option to alter that behavior, as that seems to contradict the specification, [JLS §12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1-330): “*An object o is not finalizable until its constructor has invoked the constructor for Object on o and that invocation has completed successfully (that is, without throwing an exception).*” It doesn’t look like this can still be guaranteed if the object is already registered at allocation.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that with some (very dubious) tricks this is possible, even without going through a custom native library, by (ab)using method handles.

This method essentially tricks the JVM into thinking it is currently invoking a regular method instead of a constructor.

I just have to add a mandatory "this is probably not a good idea", but this is the only way I found for doing this. I also can't attest to how this behaves on different JVMs.

### Prerequisites

To do this, an instance of `sun.misc.Unsafe` is needed. I will not go into detail about how to obtain this here since you already seem to have one, but [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe) explains the process.

### Step 1: Obtaining a trusted `MethodHandles.Lookup`

Next, a `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup` is needed to get the actual method handle for the constructor.

This class has a permission system which works through the `allowedModes` property in `Lookup`, which is set to a bunch of Flags. There is a special `TRUSTED` flag that circumvents all permission checks.

Unfortunately, the `allowedModes` field is filtered from reflection, so we cannot simply bypass the permissions by setting that value through reflection.

Even though reflecion filters can be circumvented aswell, there is a simpler way: `Lookup` contains a static field `IMPL_LOOKUP`, which holds a `Lookup` with those `TRUSTED` permissions. We can get this instance by using reflection and `Unsafe`:

```java
var field = MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredField("IMPL_LOOKUP");
var fieldOffset = unsafe.staticFieldOffset(field);

var lookup = (MethodHandles.Lookup) unsafe.getObject(MethodHandles.Lookup.class, fieldOffset);
```

We use `Unsafe` here instead of `setAccessible` and `get`, because going through reflection will cause issues with the module system in the newer java versions.

### Step 2: Finding the constructor

Now we can get a `MethodHandle` for the constructor we want to invoke. We do this by using the `Lookup` we just obtained, just like a `Lookup` would be used normally.

```java
var type = MethodType.methodType(Void.TYPE, <your constructor argument types>);
var constructor = lookup.findConstructor(<your class>, type);
```

### Step 3: Getting the `MemberName`

While the signature of `findConstructor` only specifies that it returns a `MethodHandle`, it actuall returns a `java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Constructor`. This type declares a `initMethod` field, which contains the `java.lang.invoke.MemberName` referencing our constructor. The `MemberName` type is not accessible from the outside, so all interaction with it happens through `Unsafe`.

We can obtain this `MemberName` in the same way we also obtained the `Lookup`:

```
var constructorClass = Class.forName("java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Constructor");
val initMethodField = constructorClass.getDeclaredField("initMethod");
val initMethodFieldOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(initMethodField);

var initMemberName = unsafe.getObject(constructor, initMethodFieldOffset)
```

### Step 4: Tricking Java

The next step is the important part. While there are no physical barriers from the JVM that prevent you from invoking a constructor like any other method, `MethodHandle` has some checks in place to ensure that you are not doing something fishy.

Most of the checks are circumvented by using the `TRUSTED` `Lookup`, and there remains one final check:

The `MemberName` instance contains a bunch of flags that, among other things, tell the system what kind of member the `MemberName` is referring to. These flags are checked.

To circumvent this, we can simply change the flags using `Unsafe`:

```java
var memberNameClass = Class.forName("java.lang.invoke.MemberName");
var flagsField = memberNameClass.getDeclaredField("flags");
var flagsFieldOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(flagsField);
var flags = unsafe.getInt(initMemberName, flagsFieldOffset);

flags &= ~0x00020000; // remove "is constructor"
flags |= 0x00010000; // add "is (non-constructor) method"

unsafe.putInt(initMemberName, flagsFieldOffset, flags);
```

The values for the flags come from `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.Constants#MN_IS_METHOD` and `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.Constants#MN_IS_CONSTRUCTOR`.

### Step 5: Obtaining a `REF_invokeVirtual` method handle

Now that we have a *totally legit method* that is *not at all* a constructor, we just need to obtain a regular method handle for invoking it. Luckly, `MethodHandles.Lookup.class` has a private method for turning a `MemberName` into a `(Direct)MethodHandle` for all kinds of invocations: `getDirectMethod`.

Ironically, we actually call this method using our all-powerful lookup.

First, we obtain the `MethodHandle` for `getDirectMethod`:

```
var getDirectMethodMethodHandle = lookup.findVirtual(
        MethodHandles.Lookup.class,
        "getDirectMethod",
        MethodType.methodType(
                MethodHandle.class,
                byte.class,
                Class.class,
                memberNameClass,
                MethodHandles.Lookup.class
        )
);
```

we can now use this with our lookup, to obtain a `MethodHandle` for our `MemberName`:

```java
var handle = (MethodHandle) getDirectMethod.invoke(lookup, (byte) 5, Test.class, member, lookup);
```

The `(byte) 5` argument stands for "invoke virtual", and comes from `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.Constants#REF_invokeVirtual`.

### Step 6: Profit?

We can now use this `handle` like a regular `MethodHandle`, to invoke the constructor on any existing instance of that class:

```java
handle.invoke(<instance>, <constructor arguments...>);
```

With this `handle`, the constructor can also be called multiple times, and the instance doesn't actually have to come from `Unsafe#allocateInstance` - an instance that was created just by using `new` works aswell.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is not an instance method, so no you can't invoke a constructor on an instance.

If you look at the reflection library, you'll see that the return type of [`Class.getConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) is [`Constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html), which doesn't have any methods that can accept a instance - its only relevant method is [`newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-), which doesn't accept a target instance; it creates one.

On the other hand, the return type of [`Class.getMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) is [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), whose first parameter is the instance.

A `Constructor` is not a `Method`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that part about regular reflection API. However, in JVM bytecode instance creation is two-fold: `new`, to allocate memory, and `invokespecial`, to call a constructor. So it might be possible in theory to achieve what I want

Answer (score 1):

In the [JVM spec for `invokespecial`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.invokespecial):

> An `invokespecial` instruction is type safe iff all of the following are true:
>
> ... (Stuff about non-init methods)
>
> - MethodName is `<init>`.
> - Descriptor specifies a void return type.
> - One can validly pop types matching the argument types given in Descriptor and an uninitialized type, UninitializedArg, off the incoming operand stack, yielding OperandStack.
> - ...

If you've already initialized the instance, it's not an uninitialized type, so this will fail.

Note that other `invoke*` instructions (`invokevirtual`, `invokeinterface`, `invokestatic`, `invokedynamic`) explicitly preclude invocation of `<init>` methods, so `invokespecial` is the only way to invoke them.

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS Sec 8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8)

> Constructors are invoked by class instance creation expressions (§15.9), by the conversions and concatenations caused by the string concatenation operator +(§15.18.1), and by explicit constructor invocations from other constructors (§8.8.7).
>
> ...
>
> Constructors are never invoked by method invocation expressions (§15.12).

So no, it's not possible.

If there is some common action you want to take in the constructor and elsewhere, put it into a method, and invoke that from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The JLS, however, only covers "normal" Java. E.g. it says `... it is possible to prevent class instantiation by declaring an inaccessible constructor`, without considering reflection's `setAccessible(true)` or `Unsafe`. With these things in mind, it's not at all possible to prevent class instantiation. My question is about the same level of unsafe manipulations.

Comment: Having made the constructor visible, you can still only invoke it in one of the quoted ways.

Comment: @Oleg it is possible to prevent class instantiation, even if employing reflection by declaring a (typically `private`) constructor that throws an exception. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077876/256196)

Comment: @Bohemian you can still create an instance using `Unsafe`, since, as I've already mentioned, that would not invoke your constructor.